# Flutter: Can we navigate to other screen inside controller using GetX?

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

Can I use **Get.to(OtherScreen())** inside Getx controller like the code below?

```
class UserController extends GetxController{

  Future<void> loginWithEmailAndPassword(
      {@required String email, @required String password}) async {
    
      await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email.toLowerCase(),
        password: password,
      ).then((credential){
        Get.to(OtherScreen()); // Can I use this inside controller?
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that this is not the best practice in routing, but I can't afford so much time to rework my existing project.

Answer (score 1):

Answer is yes you can. Just pass the build `context` in your method and then use the navigation route

```
Future<void> loginWithEmailAndPassword(
  {@required String email, @required String password,@required BuildContext context}) async {

  await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email.toLowerCase(),
    password: password,
  ).then((credential){
    Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => OtherScreen(),
    ),; // Can I use this inside controller?
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can navigate in controller file just replace

```
Get.to(OtherScreen());
```

to

```
Get.to(()=> OtherScreen());
```

Both Working but second is right syntax to navigate using Getx